# What am I doing wrong when passing the variable from flask to html

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to make a blog for practice in flask. I'm connecting to mysql database through mysql.connector . And the table name is 'posts' . Table has id, title, content and author columns. Everything working fine except jinja syntax {{ post.title }} isn't showing the post title(data of title column)
Can anyone help am I doing something wrong in jinja syntax or when passing the variable from flask to html..

here is my flask code:

````
@app.route('/posts', methods=['GET','POST'])
def posts():
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='shehan', password='shehan', database='blog')
    mycursor = db.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM posts")
    all_posts = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    return render_template('posts.html', ts=all_posts)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)```

------------

{% for t in ts %}
    <h2>Title: {{ t.title }}</h2>
    <h3>Post: {{ t.content }}</h3>
    <p>By: {{ t.author }}</p>
{% endfor %}
````

Browser doesn't show any error. It's working fine except {{post.title}} data isn't showing the post title from database table.
I don't see why. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: When debugging (or writing) something that has multiple moving parts, it's helpful to *isolate the parts*. You've got a database, two routes, a template with a loop and multiple variables, etc. Strip this down to *one* route, with a *simple* template (no loop, one var) and hard-coded data to render. *If* that works then *slowly* add stuff back in until it doesn't. If/when it doesn't work, ask a question about that simplified example.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code. I removed other parts of the code but still {{ t.titile}} isn't showing data..

Comment: I appreciate that you tried to take my advice, but you didn't take it nearly enough. Get rid of the database connection and use hardcoded data. Use a simpler template. Again, if it doesn't work in the *simplest* case, you don't know what isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could it be that the function name is the same as the name of returned variable?

Comment: I changed the variable name to 'ts'. but still it doesn't work. could it be a problem with the browser or such?

Comment: No, it's not the browser. Can you print 'all_posts ' and send the output?

Comment: yah i can. if i do {{ t }} then browser output is " (10, 'blog post 1', 'this is first post', 'shehan') " .  it shows the whole table row. but if i do {{ t.title }} it doesn't show..

Comment: Because that's not an object inside it is a tuple, try t[0], t[1] ...

Comment: m. yah that works.. but why can't I use {{ t.title }} I mean i have seen t.title in tutorials. Do you know a reason? may be because I installed python recently and in newer python versions t.title doesn't work?

Comment: In the tutorial, they probably pass the object and the object has attributes. In the tutorial probably one of the attributes is the title and when you pass the entire object to the template you can then access its value like t.title. Explore a little object-oriented programming to get an understanding of what an object is.